# Loading a large osm file in osmar : why does loading time scale quadratically with file size?

Tags: openstreetmap, r, xml, large-datasets

I'm trying to load huge .osm files into R in order to run advanced analysis. I did not expect the loading part to be complex, but it proved difficult.

The issue here is that **the time it takes to parse the XML file** (.osm is xml-like) and populate an object (here an osmar one) **seems to be quadratically proportional to the file size**.

```
require(osmar)
my_file = osmsource_file("filename")
osmar_object = get_osm("bla", source = my_file)
```

And in case you wonder how I found that it was quadratic, here is a representation of the analysis, with files between 0 and 500 Mo.

[image: file size quadratically impacts loading time]

*At this point, my only chance to make it work seems to be the following : split the country in 100x100 small parts, and load them separately. Obviously, I don't really like the idea.*

Why would it be so long ? How can I do so, fast ?

Answer (score 3):

I decided to implement the split / combine approach successfully. The idea is to split a .osm file into n parts, load every single part and then combine them.

1. The splitting is done with osmconvert, which provides an implementation with a bounding box. Here, I make sure every split has an overlap with its neighbors because that helps me ensure good merging performance.
2. The loading part is done normally, with get_osm.
3. The merging is done with a custom c() function, which code is available here : [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204459/r-and-osmar-how-to-merge-two-adjacent-osm-files-with-overlapping-nodes-and-way)

Thanks to this trick, was able to load countries in osmar in a few hours, which wasn't possible before (ex: France 7hours). The choice of the number of splits is the tricky part because it depends on the filesize. I tend to split in at least 50 parts, but sometimes you'll need far more.

I'm not happy with this answer though, because I still don't know why osmar ends-up taking quadratically more time loading large files. It does not make sense to me.